# Opennebula error monitoring host KVM

Tags: ruby, virtual-machine, kvm, opennebula

I've started opennebula sunstone on Ubuntu 15.04 with one host on KVM.
I can add the host on the server via sunstone, but i've an "MONITORED_ERROR" and when I look at the log I've this error: 
`/var/tmp/one/im/run_probes: line 34: 24669 Aborted ./$i $ARGUMENTS Error executing collectd-client.rb`

And if I go on the host oneadmin can log whitout password and if I execute the command: `/var/tmp/one/im/run_probes kvm /var/lib/one/datastores 4124 20 2 host` I've this error:

```
./collectd-client.rb:122:in <main>': undefined method split' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
ERROR MESSAGE --8<------
Error executing collectd-client.rb
ERROR MESSAGE ------>8--
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://forum.opennebula.org/t/solved-error-monitoring-host-2-error-executing-probes/738/3

> well, enable disable didn't work.
>   I had to delete /var/tmp/one on affected host and then :
>   su - oneadmin
>   onehost sync --force
>
> I also deleted /etc/cron.daily/tmpwatch